# Can I extend internal iPad storage?

Tags: ipad, photos, storage

Running out of space to store photos on our iPad 2. Is it possible to plug in an external storage device, move photos to it, and then be able to access those photos as if they were stored internally?

Answer (score 1):

iPad internal storage is not extensible, but you can use services like [iCloud Photos](https://www.apple.com/icloud/photos/) or [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) to store your pictures online and automatically download them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple only deploys iOS devices with internal proprietary SSD media only. Also, iPads are not modular, so you cannot change any of their components manually.

Answer (score 0):

As per the other two answers already here, Apple makes their iDevices with a fixed amount of non-modular proprietary flash storage, usually selectable upon purchase, and therefore the amount of storage inside cannot be changed.

However, there are external storage products available in the market. Some products include (but will require you to download apps):

[SanDisk Wireless Connect](https://www.sandisk.co.uk/content/sandisk-main/en_gb/home/mobile-device-storage/connect-wireless-stick)
[SanDisk iXpand](https://www.sandisk.co.uk/ixpandflashdrive)
[WD My Passport Wireless](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1330)

and many more are covered in [this Macworld article](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/iphone/best-ways-get-more-storage-for-your-iphone-or-ipad-3579792/).

Additionally, a quick search for "[external iOS storage](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=external%20ios%20storage&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb)" on your favorite search engine might bring up something more suited to your needs.